# How to get a notebook java file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written the introductory, "hello world" program in notebook.
I want it in Eclipse, and I do not want to rewrite it. How do I go about getting this file into the Eclipse editor?

Comment: import the project as java project in eclipse]

Comment: What is "notebook Java file"? As long as your file's extension is .java, Eclipse will understand it as such. Just create a project and drag it into a package

Comment: notebook Java file is an file made in notebook with extension.java. And you were right. Drag and drop was all there was to it. thx. Is there another way?

Comment: right click on project , click property , find the location of project and zip it. move the zip file to your desktop, unzip it at any location. open eclipse , right click the project area, click import--existing java project  and select the unzipped project folder to import.  for further detail, google how to import existing java project in eclipse, the first result should be helpful.    If you were talking about java file written directly in notepad, then just create java project in eclipse and copy your java file directly inside src folder.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the code, make sure the class name matches the class name in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just save your notepad file with (class name).java and paste that java file in your workspace folder, where your all the codes are being saved.